# kendo UI binding select elements

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I'm building a simple mobile application and I want to bind html select elements to an observable kendo object. 
With simple input text straightforward but with select elements am receiving a error when changing select values:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method get
```

Here is the jsfiddle example:

[JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/6ATMD/2/)

Additionally on insert button, the object is not changing the property values present on the select elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the `selects` is that you have defined a function and it needs to be an object. Try defining them as:

```
zonas       : [
    { ZonaId : 1, nome : "zona1" },
    { ZonaId : 2, nome : "zona2" }
],
estados     : [
    { estadoId : 1, nome : "activo" },
    { estadoId : 2, nome : "inactivo" }
],
utilizadores: [
    { UtilizadorId : 1, nome : "user1" },
    { UtilizadorId : 2, nome : "user2" }
]
```

Regarding the `insert` button, the problem is that `inserirEntidade` is not being invoked since it is not *visible/accessible* when you click.

You have to define this function as global.

Check it [here:](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/6ATMD/4/)

Comment: thanks it works! because my values are from localstorage i had a function. But I will create a array first and pass it to the observable object.